# Can't undraw images in Zelle graphics module

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

Whenever i draw an image onto the screen and do

```
for item in win.items[:]:
    item.undraw()
win.update()
```

It doesn't erase the image. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please supply the expected minimal, reproducible example (MRE). We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: The code you posted so far looks OK, so please [edit] your question and provide that [mre].

Comment: why do you use `[:]` ? First you could use `print()` to see if this code is executed. OR maybe it is executed before you even draw something - so it has nothing to remove. There is no answer for this problem without minimal working code which shows problem (and which we could simply copy and test).